# Vue.js Get public folder images in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, get, laravel-5.8

I am creating commenting system, now, I want to show user profile images in comment area.

I want to catch and show multiple images from laravel 5.8 public folder. Here is what I tried.

> If user has a profile image, I want to show it. If not, I want to show
>   an avatar using vue avatar component. My images are stored in
>   public/uploads/profile.

Now I don't have any errors in my console. Also I can show user name and user comments.

Image name is stored in mysql.

comment.vue(first comment)

```
<div class="user" v-if="comment.user.image && comment.user.image.length > 0">
                    <span :v-for="(item, index) in comment.user.image">
                        <img :src="'uploads/' + 'profile' + '/' + item.image">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div else class="user" >
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
                </div>
```

commentController.php

```
public function index(Post $post)
{
    return $post->comments()->paginate(10);
}

public function show(Comment $comment)
{
    return $comment->replies()->paginate(10);
}

public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{
return auth()->user()->comments()->create([
    'body' => $request->body,
    'post_id' => $post->id,
    'comment_id' => $request->comment_id
])->fresh();
}
```

profiles table

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('bod');
        $table->string('instagram');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In my VS code, uploads folder started turning red.

Comment: check your `img` `src` tag and see what url is generated after page render

Comment: Have you tried using the a preceding  ' / '  `/uploads/...` ?  In my projects I always need the preceding slash.

Comment: '' + item.image' seems very wired.

Comment: @skribe I tried but it didn't work

Comment: As @Vibha said, what does the final rendered src attribute look like?

Comment: vue-avater--wrapper . Sorry I checked Elements in chrome dev tool. Is this what you are asking for ? If not, how can I check the final rendered src ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is create a api route to show image. For example.

**api.php**

```
Route::get('profile/{fileName}', 'ProfileController@showImage');
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
class ProfileController {
    ...
    public function showImage($fileName)
    {
        $path = public_path("/images/{$fileName}");

        if (!\File::exists($path)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Image not found.'], 404);
        }

        $file = \File::get($path);
        $type = \File::mimeType($path);

        $response = \Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

And you image src will be `/api/profile/{imageName}`. This is my solution.

Comment: Thank you,  it didn't work, so I changed public_path("/images/{$fileName}"); by public_path("/uploads/profile/{$fileName}"); .My new error now is :8000/api/profile/[object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost:8000/api/profile/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This path just for example. You should edit the right path by yourself.

Comment: Yes I think my public path is '/' + 'uploads' + '/'  + 'profile' + '/' + $fileName so I did. But still it doesn't. Thanks for help me anyway.

Comment: Did you create route on your `api.php`?

Comment: Not yet I have only Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Comment: You should create laravel route first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201074/discussion-between-yohei-umezu-and-lighter).